# Convergence of series of expectations implies finite stopping time?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, stopping-times

Let $a_1,a_2,\dots $ be a sequence of random variables. They are not assumed i.i.d.
Say that $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[|a_k|^2] := A < \infty.$$

For $\epsilon> 0$, define the stopping time$$T_{\epsilon} = \inf\{ k \mid |a_k| < \epsilon\}.$$ Does $T_{\epsilon}$ necessarily have finite expectation? and can I bound $\mathbb{E}[T_{\epsilon}]$ in terms of $A$ and $\epsilon$?

In the deterministic case, this is straightforward:

If $T_{\epsilon} \geq \lceil \frac{A}{\epsilon^2}\rceil$ then 
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_i|^{2} > \frac{A}{\epsilon^2} \epsilon^2 = A,$$
a contradiction.  Can any similar result be proven for the stochastic case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E\sum _{k=1}^{T_\epsilon -1} a_k ^{2} \leq E\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} a_k ^{2} = A$. This gives $E\sum _{k=1}^{T_\epsilon -1} \epsilon^{2} \leq A$. Hence $ET_{\epsilon} \leq 1+\frac A {{\epsilon}^{2}}$. ( $T_\epsilon -1$ need not be an integer, so an obvious modification is needed, but I will that to you).

Comment: Thanks @Kavi. When I followed your reasoning, I ended up with $1 + A/\epsilon^2$, rather than $1+ A^{2}/\epsilon$. Also, when you say that $T_{\epsilon} - 1$ need not be an integer, what exactly do you mean? Is it that it could be $\infty$, or something else?

Comment: It could be  between two integers. Use the greatest integer less than or equal to this number. You will have to change the bound to $2+A/(\epsilon)^{2}$

Comment: $1+\frac A {{\epsilon}^{2}}$ is right. There was a typo which put square in the wrong place.